# Datatables Buttons not Showing If I have an AJAX script running

Tags: ajax, datatables

I have this two block of codes below,

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable({
      "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
      "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
    }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
      "responsive": true,
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
function getdistrict(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxfile.php",
data:'state_id='+val,
success: function(data){
$("#district-list").html(data);
}
});
}
</script>
```

If I remove the AJAX script the buttons appear but I need this script to work.

Comment: I don't understand.  What happens if you leave the AJAX call in there?  That function should have no impact on the data tables.

Comment: That’s what i wonder too, if i remove the Ajax script the buttons from the datatables appears above the table but if i leave it there it does not show, somebody in the community said that this needs to have an initComplete.

Comment: Are you CALLING that `getdistrict` function?  Where?

Comment: Yes i am using this getdistrict on a form for a dynamic dropdown, Here is the code.

`<select onChange="getdistrict(this.value);"  name="sector" id="state"  class="form-control" required>`

Comment: But that won't get called until the `<select>` changes, after the page is already set up.

Comment: damn just an old ajax api is the problem, thank you @TimRoberts for the help, it is much appreciated. cheers brother
i was using this<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> instead of <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newbie mistake of using an old jQuery API like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead of using this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```